# facebook-c#-sdk FQL query returns JSON, can I get XML

Tags: xml, json, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-fql

I have facebook app using Facebook Developer Toolkit for several years.
The FQL queries return XML

Now using facebook-c#-sdk, FQL query returns JSON, I can not find any options to specify format.

Can I get the same XML facebook returned from FQL before?

Can Graph API return XML?

How is this specified using the facebook-c#-sdk?

thanks,
Ben

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you can specify format in your api call as per documentation on http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/ :

format=json or format=sql

https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=QUERY&format=json

Comment: Yes it does work to specify format=xml when directly making call to facebook and that is what I ended up doing, however there is no way to pass format parameter via C# SDK.  So I

Comment: This is the answer to "Can Graph API return XML?"

Answer (score 0):

Even if you pass `format=xml` Facebook C# SDK overwrites it to `format=json` internally before making the request..